# Как вывести Response в alert()

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

Мне нужно вывести `response.errors.detail` как строку в `alert`. При попытке `alert(response.errors.detail)` получаю уведомление: `[object Object]`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/create/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
         email: this.email,
         username: this.login,
         password: this.password
    },
    success: (response) => {
            alert("Аккаунт зарегистрирован");
            this.$router.push({name: 'home'})
    },
    error: (response) => {
            alert(response.errors.detail)
    }
 })
```

Ответ POST запроса:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "detail": "Введённый пароль слишком похож на имя пользователя.",
            "source": {
                "pointer": "/data/attributes/password"
            },
            "status": "400"
        },
}
```

Comment: `response.errors` в вашем коде массив?

Comment: Что приходит в response ?

Comment: Посмотрите скриншот лога
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/040619/ShDagvCk?a

Comment: В вашей ситуации это массив, и нужно вывести в цикле или подготовить строку перед выводом.

Answer (score 0):

Вот перебор и вывод ошибок.

```
  let result = '';
  response.errors.forEach((el) => {
    result += `${el.detail} \n`;
  });
  alert(result)
```

```js
const response = {
  "errors": [{
    "detail": "Введённый пароль слишком похож на имя пользователя.",
    "source": {
      "pointer": "/data/attributes/password"
    },
    "status": "400"
  }, {
    "detail": "Ошибка 2",
    "source": {
      "pointer": "/data/attributes/password"
    },
    "status": "400"
  }, {
    "detail": "Ошибка 3",
    "source": {
      "pointer": "/data/attributes/password"
    },
    "status": "400"
  }, ]
}

error = () => {
  let result = '';
  response.errors.forEach((el) => {
    result += `${el.detail} \n`;
  });
  alert(result)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="error()">test</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Удалось вывести с помощью команды:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(response.responseJSON.errors['0'].detail));
```

Не удивляйтесь, у меня сначала тоже глаза на лоб полезли :/